# $_SESSION in PHP: variable not read on page reload

Tags: php, session

When I set a session variable, I think it is not read:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['last_activity'])){
if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) { 
   //...
}else{ 
   session_destroy();
   session_start();    
   $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); // setting variable
   $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 8*60*60;  // calculate exp.time
   echo "branch 1";
}
}else{  
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); // setting variable
   $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 8*60*60; // calculate exp.time
   echo "branch 2";
}
?>
```

on page reload, it is considered always "branch 2".
If I put 'session_start();' at the top of the page, for every reloads it jumps from branch 1.1 to 1.2:

Comment: You seem to not start the session unless a condition is met. Put `session_start()` at the top, directly after `<?php`, and remove it from everywhere else in that file.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you Qirel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session not starting in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975960/session-not-starting-in-php)

Comment: Take note also that session_start() must comes before any character is printed on the screen. This means that session_start() must be in the very first line of your code. Otherwise, you will get a PHP warning.

Comment: All of you got me the same exact answer...I don't know how to vote you all.

Comment: now, for every reload,  it jumps from branch 1.2 to branch 2...is it maybe up to "session_destroy();" ???

Answer (score 1):

You need to start session before first if condition.Because you dont start your session before checking `SESSION` is exist or not

```
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['last_activity'])){
if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) { 
   //...
}else{ 


   $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); 
   $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 8*60*60;  
   echo "branch 1";
   session_destroy();
}
}else{  
   $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); // setting variable
   $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 8*60*60; 
   echo "branch 2";
   session_destroy();
}
```

UPDATE:

> Its enough to start session before if condition and whan the condition enters the else just destroy it

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to set a session variable that you destroy immediately after. Not really clear what OPs intent of destroying the session is (might confused what it does?).

Answer (score 0):

Try it, Its working fine.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['last_activity'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['last_activity'] < time() - $_SESSION['expire_time']) {

    } else {
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 8 * 60 * 60;
        echo "branch 1";
    }
} else {

    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); // setting variable
    $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 8 * 60 * 60;
    echo "branch 2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a detail: now, for every reload, it jumps from branch 1.2 to branch 2...is it maybe up to "session_destroy();" ???
In that case, I don't know how to reset my session once it expires.